# Calculation in Einstein Analytics Dashboard JSON - dynamic reference line

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, dynamic-binding, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I am adding a dynamic reference line to a combo widget and the line needs to show an average conversion rate.

Monthly conversion rate is presented well, as the column calculating this value is set to Custom % - so although I am seeing visually 42% etc, looking at the axis on the left, it sits between 0 and 1.

When using a binding query to bring in the average YTD conversion rate

"{{cell(ConvertedOpp_1.result, 0, \"C\").asString()}}"

I am seeing 0.42

Is there a way to change JSON so that the value itself for the dynamic reference line sits between 0 and 1, however, the visual shows 42?

Ie, is it possible to do something like this in reference line's label or value section in JSON?

"{{cell(ConvertedOpp_1.result, 0, \"C\").asString()}}" * 100

Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ConvertedOpp_1 query, you could add a field with C*100 to bind it in the reference line label. Then to not have it displayed in other charts/tables remove it from the JSONs "numbers": [],
"groups": [],
"strings": []
section of the query.

Alternatively create a new query, where you bind "{{cell(ConvertedOpp_1.result, 0, \"C\").asString()}}" and multiply it by 100. (Perhaps attach "%") Then bind this querys result in the reference line label.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much Patrick! I've gone for the first option - it's working exactly as I wanted. Just another quick question, I can't seem to be able to get rid of the decimal points, although the column in ConvertedOpp_1 is set to be a number with no decimal points, ie in the query I see 42, and on the reference line label I see 42.1052631.... etc , thank you!

Comment: The Format is only applied to the shown output, not the underlying number. To remove the decimal places, surround the calculation with trunc(    )

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!